# Adding email client send button as right bar button item

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, uibarbuttonitem

I searched in forums but could find a way to do this.

Is there any way to add the default email client Send button without using an image view?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `UIBarButtonSystemItemAction`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *sendMailButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(btnActionPressed)] autorelease];
```

And don't forget:

```
- (IBAction)btnActionPressed {
// code
}
```